# Why is my Overpass Request not returning small creeks, but only the major water bodies

Tags: overpass-api

I have this request:

```
    /*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“water”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “water”
  way["natural"="water"](46.718739800819776,8.407201766967773,46.744507241875134,8.450760841369627);
  relation["natural"="water"](46.718739800819776,8.407201766967773,46.744507241875134,8.450760841369627);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I expect all water bodies to be returned by this request but only polygons and points are in the result. Lines are missing.

See the picture

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because the lines aren't tagged as `natural=water`, but as `waterway=stream`

So you'd need to add that to your query, e.g. via:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“water”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “water”
  way["natural"="water"](46.718739800819776,8.407201766967773,46.744507241875134,8.450760841369627);
  way["waterway"](46.718739800819776,8.407201766967773,46.744507241875134,8.450760841369627);
  relation["natural"="water"](46.718739800819776,8.407201766967773,46.744507241875134,8.450760841369627);
  relation["waterway"](46.718739800819776,8.407201766967773,46.744507241875134,8.450760841369627);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Generally, it's useful to review the OSM data at the location for which you're writing the query. You don't even need to install software for that - just click the "Edit" button on openstreetmap.org to open the web editor and be able to inspect the attributes of any map feature.